# Stream camera and audio feed to google meet using python

Tags: python

I want to stream my audio and camera captured by python to google meet. currently, I am capturing my webcam using "open cv" so I need suggestion for an audio capturing lib and how to make it selectable as media input in google meet

Comment: using `opencv` with other module for `audio` can be big problem to synchronize video with audio. Better try to use modules which send both - ie. `ffmpeg`.

Comment: there are tools to create fake webcam - at least on Linux - [pyfakewebcam](https://github.com/jremmons/pyfakewebcam). I found also [webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/)

Comment: @furas can u suggest any library or package for same? I am currently trying webcamoid , will update here

Comment: I never tried to send stream to Google Meet or any other tool (ie. Zoom). For streaming camera or my desktop or some window on desktop I would try something different - [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) but this doesn't let you use `opencv` to modify stream. YouTube [OBS To Google Meet | How to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfDaUjOXc-8)

Comment: @furas obs is the thing that can help, thnx mate now just need to do the audio part, actually, as my laptop run in safe mode it can't use microphone or webcam and yesterday i accessed web came using python, just figuring audio too

Comment: @furas just as virtual cam, I tried several virtual microphones but they are not working, they do not show up in list while selecting a microphone

Comment: do you have problem with microphon when you use normal audio software - ie. [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) ? Maybe problem is only system Linux, not virtual cam.

Comment: @furas actually, the problem is windows do not load drivers for the microphone in safe mode, and neither it loads for webcam, but somehow webcam is working and mic doesn't